# Neo4j-jdbc hangs at creating only 10 nodes

Tags: java, neo4j

My use case is to create nodes in remote neo4j.
The java code attempts to create 22 nodes but at 11th node it hangs on execute query.

By the way, I use the desci field to put the node key-value description in order to deserialize it later. T is a generic object that has a getMap function.

```
public Long[] put(T[] a)  throws SQLException,BiopolisGeneralException
{
    Long[] ids=new Long[a.length];
    int index=0;
    for(T x : a)
    {          
        System.out.println(index+"  count  "+a.length);
        String json=(new Gson()).toJson(x);
        System.out.println(json);
        Map<String,Object> map=x.getMap();            
        String desci=Base64.encodeBase64String(json.getBytes());
        map.put("desci",desci);
        String queryString=" CREATE (n:"+this.nodetype+
                " {1} )  RETURN ID(n)";
        Map<String,Object> mm=new HashMap<String,Object>();
        mm.put("1", map);
        ResultSet rs=this.bgr.conn.executeQuery(queryString, mm);
        if(!rs.next())
        {                
            throw new BiopolisGeneralException("Cannot create "+json);
        }
        else
        {
            Long id=rs.getLong(1);
            System.out.println(id);
            ids[index++]=id;
        }
        System.out.println("do");
    }
    System.out.println("ok");
    return ids;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a guess, but is there a limit of 10 being hit somewhere by not explicitly closing the result sets?  Try adding `rs.close()` after your `else` clause and see if that makes a difference.

If it does work, you might want to use it in a try-finally block for robustness.

Comment: It worked like charm. Thank you very much. I will wrap it to a try with resources.

Comment: Yeah, try-with-resources would be best.  Feel free to mark my answer as accepted, by the way ;-)